# What is the prevailing direction of Riemannian geometry now?

Tags: soft-question, riemannian-geometry, career-development

I spent months working on a meaningless problem. And what's worse is I fail to prove it.  Although I am rookie, I want to know the prevailing direction of Riemannian geometry. Besides, the Poincare conjecture has been proved for more than  decade.  And seemly,  many problems that can be solved by Ricci flow have also been solved. And seemly, Ricci flow is weak for 4-dim  problems.  So, is it worth spending a lot of time on Ricci flow now ?

I don't  know how a trivial math practitioner should spend his life.  And I don't like teaching. So I felt lost. I was hoping to get some advice. Thanks.

Comment: Not accurately addressing your question, but Ricci-flow is a current hot topic in dimension 4

Comment: There is no "prevailing direction of RG." If you are a student or a postdoc, then you should talk to your advisor. Otherwise, you are expected to be familiar with some subarea of RG which is your specialty and to know lists of open problems, etc.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51068/open-questions-in-riemannian-geometry

Comment: You can watch some videos on BiliBili or YouTube. Search for topology or Riemann geometry. Moreover, have a look at “Lectures on differential geometry” written by Yau and Scheon maybe useful for you. You can try to do some “simple” problem first and find some problems you are really interested.in. You know, interest is the best motivation.

Comment: @HONGHAOJIEYOU  I've been spending a lot of time studying physics recently. Feynman's lectures on physics seemed like a good diversion.

Comment: That’s really cool!